# Include Spring MVC in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans, frameworks

Using Netbeans 7.3, Spring MVC does not seem to be bundled with the IDE. I thought this would be the case, but only JavaServer Faces and Hibernate are included when it comes to web frameworks. Do I have to activate it somehow? In Eclipse it is easy to download additional frameworks from within the IDE. How do I do this in Netbeans? I use glassfish locally, but that's OK with Spring MVC isn't it?

Comment: If you have JSH and Hibernate then you should have Spring Web MVC available too (I have it). Please explain what kind of project you created and how did you do it.

Comment: I created a web application and chose glassfish 3+. From what I remember, I used to be able to choose between JSF, Hibernate, Spring MVC and Struts, but the latter 2 have vanished. Can't remember when I last saw those two framework options,though; perhaps I was using 7.1 or 7.2 back then. Like you say, it should still be bundled with the 7.3 so it's a bit puzzling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just created a Web Project like the one in your comment and Spring MVC is there in NB 7.3. (Windows, Java 7)

Anyway, the following steps should help you recover it:

1. Open the *Tools > Plugins* window and go to *Installed* tab
2. Check the *Show details* box and look for *Spring Web MVC* ,it might be installed but deactivated. In that case activate it.
3. In case is not installed then go to the tab *Available plugins*
4. Look for *Spring Web MVC* and install it
5. Restart NetBeans

Comment: Glad it wasn't an obscure problem with your installation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use maven too.
You don't have to master it, just add dependencies for the time being. And it would still work in case you switch your IDE.

Comment: Alright, but I can't see the point of it. Why do you find Maven better at adding dependencies than the default Ant foundation that Netbeans builds from? I gather this is one of those religious topics, but is Maven and Spring particularly useful when used together?

Comment: I think it's just a matter of preference, or your develop environment. You may want to have a look at [this post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/maven_vs_ant).

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans includes full Maven support since version 6.7.  I would use Maven to pull in the spring dependencies by adding them in the pom.xml file.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure if I'm up to learning Maven at the moment. As the dependencies should be there by default I think there should be a way to activate Spring MVC in the IDE without explicitly adding dependencies. Perhaps this is a bug, I've had a couple of issues before in 7.3. Maybe I need to reinstall Netbeans but I'd rather find out what the issue originates from.